# Criar rotas usando o Route do React

Tags: react-router

Seguinte estou utilizando o react-router-dom enquanto estou servindo a pasta do projeto como se fosse raiz funciona, as rotas vão para os componentes específicos meu problema é quando eu coloco em um servidor:

a parte do front onde está o react eu coloco dentro da pasta /app e meus scripts php que interagem com o front em /server.

diferente quando eu coloco o react na raiz / que funciona perfeitamente.

```
<Router>
    <div>
      <a href="./">inicio</a><span> </span>
      <a href="./maps">maps</a><span> </span>
      <a href="./cadastro">cadastro</a>


      <Route path={"/app/maps"} component={TelaMaps} />
      <Route path={"/app/cadastro"} component={TelaCadastro} />

    </div>
  </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu problema é a rota que você faz no seu servidor para os arquivos do React.

Se você está usando webpack e express basta você fazer uma combinação dos dois para servir seus arquivos no lugar desejado.

Um exemplo:

Webpack output:

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
```

Express configuração:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('dist'));
```

Comment: Infelizmente eu não estou utilizando o node, meu projeto é com o PHP usando o stack com APACHE.

Comment: Coloca as configurações que você tem